# $(3/4) \cdot (8/9) \cdot (15/16) \cdot \ldots$ How to prove that limit is $1/2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

How can one prove $$\frac34 \cdot  \frac89 \cdot \cdots \cdot \frac{n^2-1}{n^2}$$ has a limit $1/2$?

I tried some manipulations with the terms with no success and have just no idea,
Thanks

Comment: please take a look here http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference and try to use LaTeX when writing mathematical formulas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rewrite each $1-\frac{1}{k^2}$ as $\frac{(k-1)(k+1)}{k^2}$ and observe the mass cancellations.

$$\left(\frac{3}{2}\frac{4}{3}\frac{5}{4}\cdots\frac{n}{n-1}\frac{n+1}{n}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{1}{2}\frac{2}{3}\frac{3}{4}\cdots\frac{n-2}{n-1}\frac{n-1}{n}\right)$$

After mass cancellations, pull the $$\frac{n+1}{2}\text{ and }\frac{1}{n}$$

$$\frac{n+1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{n}$$

Limit of this function tending to infinity $= 1/2$.

This question has been ansewred million times in this site.

Goodluck

Comment: thank you. Now it is clear

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 11):

*Hint:* The $k^{th}$ term in the product $\dfrac{k^2 - 1}{k^2} = \dfrac{(k-1)(k+1)}{k^2}$, try to see if there is some cancellation with the adjacent terms. The final expression should be simple enough to take limit.